# Как забрать нужное значение из json файла?

Tags: angularjs

Есть файл

```
[{
"ru": "пользователь",
"en":"user"
}],
```

есть контроллер

```
 vm.locale = ...
 vm.content = homeService.get({locale:vm.locale});
```

и есть сервис

```
   function homeService($resource) {

    return $resource('core/server/json/json.json',{locale: '@locale'});
}
```

Можно ли из файла json забрать только "ru" или "en"?
 Ну т.е. сделать что-то вроде

```
   function homeService($resource) {

    return $resource('core/server/json/json.json/:locale',{locale: '@locale'});
}
```

Или это можно только если это полноценный API? Какой должен быть синтаксис, чтобы выдернуть из json только по locale?

Или, в этом случае, нужно только отдельные файлы делать?

Comment: Стоит выбрать другой подход. Я так полагаю "Есть файл" - это файл с локал только для одного слова - `user` ? Не тру - придется для каждой фразы заводить файлы. Лучше создать для каждой локали свой файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для каждой локали создайте свой файл. Создайте сервис, получающий json для текущей локали и возвращающий объект.